# Tabelas coligadas: O que é? Como é? Pra que serve? O que justifica seu uso?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gostaria de uma explicação melhor dessa estratégia (se assim for denominada) e o que faz ser justificado o seu uso já que vejo alguns sistemas comerciais utilizando disso.

Complementação da pergunta:

Bom, eu também nunca tinha visto pessoalmente, só havia ouvido falar desse termo (se assim posso chamar) até que um dia me deparei com uma grande instituição que utilizava essa "estratégia". Fui fazer uma prova de computação lá e todos os analistas só falavam em "coligada", "coligada"...  Pelo que vi (ou entendi superficialmente) tratava-se de uma tabela de índice que servia como um identificador a mais para todas as outras tabelas do sistema do qual para se fazer QUALQUER consulta no sistema eu precisaria dar um join nesta tabela... Talvez uma estratégia de segurança que justifique o uso mas achei extremamente desnecessário e redundante.

Comment: Acredito que esteja falando de uma tabela chamada "coligada" e não uma estratégia de banco. 

Houve uma confusão. Programas como o TOTVS utilizam uma tabela chamada "coligada" para separar os registros entre as filiais da empresa que está usando o sistema. 

Ou seja para obter qualquer dado do banco de dados, é necessário fazer um `JOIN` com a tabela `coligada` para conseguir separar os dados da filial ou "coligada" que deseja. veja ´só alguns links do manual 

https://goo.gl/RSBNp6

http://wikihelp.totvs.com.br/WikiHelp/FOP/Fop.CopiaTabCalcColigadas.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Olá  Vinícius, não ouvi falar de "tabelas coligadas"... O que eu vejo muito em Banco de dados são Tabelas relacionadas.

Cada tabela possui sua PK (Chave primaria), e esta primary key pode ser uma FK( Chave estrangeira de outra tabela.

As tabelas relacionadas trabalham de acordo com seu código.

Muito utilizada em grandes sistemas(erp), ecommerce, sistemas simples(estoque, venda) e afins.

Exemplo: A chave ID_Categoria de uma tabela Categoria é uma FK na tabela Produtos.

Quando você for listar este produto poderá ser exibido a categoria também.

Tabelas relacionadas são de suma importância para qualquer banco de dados de sua aplicação.

Comment: Bom, eu também nunca tinha visto pessoalmente, só havia ouvido falar desse termo (se assim posso chamar) até que um dia me deparei com uma grande instituição que utilizava essa "estratégia". Fui fazer uma prova de computação lá e os analistas só falavam em "coligada", "coligada"... Pelo que vi(ou entendi superficialmente) tratava-se de uma tabela de índices que servia como um identificador a mais para todas as outras tabelas do sistema. Para se fazer uma consulta eu precisaria dar um join nesta tabela. Talvez uma estratégia de segurança mas achei extremamente desnecessário e redundante...

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você se refere à tabelas relacionadas correto ?

O relacionamento entre tabelas é uma das premissas de um banco de dados relacional (SQL), a construção de tabelas utilizando relacionamentos ajuda a localização de registros que tem alguma referência com determinado registro.

Por exemplo:

Imagine a situação de uma venda por exemplo, se você não utilizar relacionamento entre tabelas, sua tabela `venda` teria que possuir todos os dados pertinentes à ela, ou seja.

Imagine que o vendedor Lucas fez 5 vendas.
De maneira bem simplória, você teria algo assim:

[image: Tabela 1]

Repare que se o vendedor fizer 1000 vendas para o mesmo cliente, as informações serão repetidas 1000 vezes, além de aumentar o risco de ter inconsistência dos dados. (Posso digitar Lucas em um campo, lucas em outro,Lucasd em outro) etc...

Para isso que serve o relacionamento.

Você atribui um identificador para cada registro, e sempre que for usá-lo você usa a referência desse registro.

[image: Tabela 2]

O campo `id` seria o que chamamos de chave primária, um identificador único para aquele registro (não precisa ser um número inteiro, você pode usar qualquer campo ou conjunto de campos para identificar um registro)

Quando apontamos para uma chave primária que está em outra tabela, essa chave passa a ser referida como chave estrangeira (Foreign key), (para efeito de entendimento, normalmente cria-se o relacionamento, e atribui-se regras para essa chave estrangeira).

Bom, finalizando, acredito que só há sentido em usar um banco relacional se você for usar os relacionamentos.

Se sua aplicação não precisa de relacionamentos, ou você não pretende usar os relacionamentos, creio que seria mais vantajoso utilizar bancos não relacionais( os chamados NoSql).

Comment: Não se trata disso que estou falando mesmo assim muito obrigado pela resposta.